# Ubuntu 17.04 installer freezes on boot text right after choosing to install

Tags: system-installation, 17.04, usb-installation, nomodeset, visual-artifacts

This question is not a duplicate of: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
There is no purple screen nor black screen and the problem comes out while some loading text is printed.

The error happens before the GUI has loaded. It happens during the loading while some loading texts are shown.

Hardware:
  standard preassembled motherboard
  Intel Core i7 3770
  Nvidia GTX 970
  standard Western Digital hard drive

[image]
<sup>**Photo of the screen while freezing on loading text**</sup>

Comment: You could at least post the hardware specs.

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset`, then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 Actually I looked at the instructions to use nomodeset, I can't even load the live cd because of this problem. It happens before the boot of the GUI.

Comment: It is done before the GUI is loaded.

Comment: Another way is to connect monitor to the Intel adapter, install the system, then install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was a subset of two other problems, here is how I fixed it:

First of all I enabled the BIOS emulation in my UEFI setup, by doing this I could then boot (manually) the USB installer in BIOS mode instead of UEFI mode.

Then I fixed the problem with the GPU by changing the installer settings (up arrow-->choose language-->f6-->nomodeset, during the boot of the installator) and ran the installation.